# meteor saying Iron Router is unresolved with Intellij

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, intellij-idea, iron-router

I'm using Intellij and Meteor to make an application and I'm trying to use Iron Router to create multiple pages, but when I call the Router in the Javascript file, it says that Router is an unresolved variable and that route is an unresolved function or method. I've checked the meteor folder and it appears that all the Iron Router files loaded fine. At the bottom of the root page I am working on it says

> Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url:
>   "http://localhost:3000/."

If I navigate to http://localhost:3000/about, which is the only page I have a route set up for yet, the page is blank, except for my nav bar.

Here is my javascript file...

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection("items");
Found_items = new Mongo.Collection("found_items");

Router.route('home', {path: '/'}); // Add this route
Router.route('about', {path: '/about'});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    items: function () {
      return Items.find({});
    },
    found_items: function () {
      return Found_items.find({});
    },
    priceSum: function(){

      var userItems = Found_items.find({
        userId: this._id
      }).fetch();

      var prices = _.pluck(userItems, "price");

      var totalTaxed = _.reduce(prices, function(sum, price){
        var total = sum + parseFloat(price);
        return total + (total * 0.04712);
      }, 0);

      return totalTaxed.toFixed(2);
    },
    calcTax: function () {
      var userItems = Found_items.find({
        userId: this._id
      }).fetch();

      var prices = _.pluck(userItems, "price");

      var tax =  _.reduce(prices, function(sum, price){
        return (sum + parseFloat(price)) * 0.04712;
      }, 0);

      return tax.toFixed(2);
    }
  });


  Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-item": function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var text = event.target.text.value;

      Items.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        owner: Meteor.userId(),
        username: Meteor.user().username
      });

      event.target.text.value = "";
    }
  });

  Template.item.events({
    "click .found": function (event, template) {

      event.preventDefault();
      var price = template.find('[name="price"]').value;
      var text = template.find('.text').textContent;

      Items.remove(this._id);
      Found_items.insert({
        text: text,
        price: price
      });

    }
  });

  Template.body.events({
    "click .remove": function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      Found_items.remove(this._id);
    }
  });

  Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
  });
}
```

And here is the HTML file

```
<head>
  <title>Grocery List</title>
</head>

<template name="home">
<body>
<div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menuItem">{{> loginButtons}}</li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'home'}}" class="menuLink">Home</a> </li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'about'}}" class="menuLink">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
{{#if currentUser}}
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1 id="title">Grocery List</h1>

    <form class="new-item">
      <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new items" />
    </form>
  </header>

  <ul>
    {{#each items}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Items Found</h1>
  </header>

  <ul>
    {{#each found_items}}
      {{> found}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h3>
      Tax: ${{calcTax}}
    </h3>
    <h2>
      Total: ${{priceSum}}
    </h2>
    <button class="save">Save list</button>
  </header>
</div>
{{else}}
  <h3>Please log in first.</h3>
{{/if}}
</body>
</template>

<template name="item">
  <li>
    <button class="found">Got it!</button>

    <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="Sale Price" />

    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>

<template name="found">
  <li>
    <button class="remove">&times;</button>
    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
    <span class="price">{{price}}</span>
  </li>
</template>

<template name="about">
  <head>
    <title>About Grocery List</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menuItem">{{> loginButtons}}</li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'home'}}" class="menuLink">Home</a> </li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'about'}}" class="menuLink">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div  class="container">
    <header><h1>About</h1></header>
    <p>This application was created using Meteor. It can be used to make, save and update grocery lists. Once the user is in the store, they can use it to check off items on the list, put in the price and see the total, with tax.<br>
      Users can also save their previous lists to either reuse them, or compare current prices to previous ones.<br>
      Future implementations of this page would also allow the user to change the tax rate depending on their location, and include coupons and other discounts in the pricing.</p>
  </div>
  </body>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always add a route for the root.

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection("items");
Found_items = new Mongo.Collection("found_items");

Router.route('home', {path: '/'}); // Add this route
Router.route('about', {path: '/about'});
```

BTW, you have a `head` and `body` section within your template. That is rendered but does not have an effect in your browser.

Use the following syntax with IR's template helper `pathFor`:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menuItem">{{> loginButtons}}</li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'home'}}">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'about'}}" class="menuLink">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

In order to get your code working, I also fixed a couple of issues:

- Removed head and body tags in templates.
- Renamed Template.body.helpers to Template.home.helpers.
- Renamed Template.body.events to Template.home.events.

Now it is adding new items to the collection and showing items.

Comment: Thanks for those tips, but it doesn't address the issue of IntelliJ saying that the Router object is an unresolved variable. It seems that none of the Javascript for IR will work until that issue is resolved.

Comment: You still get the message 'Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url' after setting the route for the root route? BTW, I don't use IntelliJ myself but I was able to reproduce the IR message about missing routes.

Comment: No, in fact with those I don't get anything rendering except my nav bar. Could it be because I have other templates that are used withing what would be my "Home" template?

Comment: Not sure. I would have to see more of your templates and code to judge that. If you open up the debug console in Chrome, enter the address (`http://localhost:3000`), and look at messages that come in on the console? See something strange? Or any message at all?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the console. I've edited it so you can see the whole files.

Comment: I ran your code but it seems nothing is working at all. No items are added to the collection and items are not shown. I think that what you ask is solved by my previous answer. Navigation works as you navigate between  home and about.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you about this, but now I have the routing working, but none of the clickables (the text input or any of the buttons) seem to be working now. They render, but I can't click then, I can't put text into the text input, my cursor doesn't even change when I hover over it.

Comment: Then start a new question, this one is sort of solved. I cannot write the whole program for you. Did you try my latest additions to the answer? About renaming `body` to `home`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a route with / to call localhost:3000

**routing example**

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',  
});

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');  
},{
    name: 'home'
});

Router.route('/about', function () {
  this.render('about');
},{
    name: 'about'
});
```

**html**

```
<template name="layout">             
  {{> yield}}              
</template>

<template name="home">
    <p>i am the homepage</p>
</template>

<template name="about">
    <p>i am the about page</p>
</template>
```